# Slim Authentication middleware for all routes except someone

Tags: php, authentication, middleware, slim-3

I would like to have a Slim middleware to check authentication on all requests but some specific ones (for example login page).
I prepared the first `AuthenticationMiddleware` middleware to check all pages:

```
$app->add(new \App\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware($container));
```

Then I create another one `AnonymousMiddleware` that it is supposed to add a variable to set the exception to authentication checks:

```
$app->group('',function() use ($app){
    $app->get('/','LogicController:index');    
})->add(new AnonymousMiddleware($container));
```

The problem is that routes middleware (AnonymousMiddleware) is applied AFTER the general middleware (AuthenticationMiddleware);

I tried to use `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` but it doesn't change the result.

I know I would set a route middleware for all authenticated routes but sounds a bit dangerous if I forget it, so, I would prefer to set which router are not under authentication then keep the check all other routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to chose different approach

you need to wrap all routes which should be "protected via Auth middleware" and exclude = not wrap routes which should not be handled by this middleware

you can add a group where all your routes will live and only login (and logout) route will be outside of this group ;)

something like

```
$app->group("/api/v1", function() { 
 // all your protected routes definitions here
})
->add(AuthenticationMiddleware::class)); // wrap by middleware

$app->post('/login', function(){});

$app->add(new MiddlewareForAllRoutes()); // middlewares for all routes
```

Comment: Yes, thanks seems there is not other choice to invert the logic.